# Timezone obtained via TimezoneFinder, 'America/Ciudad_Juarez', generates error UnknowTimeZone with pytz

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

I retrieve timezones from airports of the world, using `TimezoneFinder().timezone_at` applied on longitude and latitude of airports. And when I want to use these timezones (to compute times of departure ad arrival of flights) everything works except ***America/Ciudad_Juarez***.
This simple code:

```
from timezonefinder import TimezoneFinder
from pytz import timezone
tz = TimezoneFinder().timezone_at(lng=-106.48333, lat=31.73333)
# retrieves 'America/Ciudad_Juarez'
timezone(tz)
```

Generates this error:

```
UnknownTimeZoneError: 'America/Ciudad_Juarez'
```

I checked in [this excellent wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), this timezone is correct, *canonical* they say. I am surprised that a timezone obtained through `timezonefinder` is not recognised by `pytz`. How can I cleanly solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This timezone was only very recently added, as Ciudad Juárez decided to align it's time with the US for DST. See http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2022-November/000076.html for the announcement. It looks like pytz has not been updated to include that change just yet.

Comment: in the meantime, what timezone should I replace it with in my dataset? America/Chihuahua ?

Comment: The other answer suggests you should use zoneinfo instead, which would be the correct thing to do. Otherwise either times in the past or times in the future will be wrong depending on which replacement you pick.

Comment: I'm still on pytz for now, so I had to make sure that the tzdata dependency was at version [2022.7](https://github.com/python/tzdata/blob/master/NEWS.md)

Answer (score 3):

[pytz is deprecated](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/). No issues with Python 3.9+ [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html):

```py
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

print(datetime.now(ZoneInfo("America/Ciudad_Juarez")))
# 2022-12-15 12:14:07.369739-07:00
```

(Python 3.9.15 on GNU/Linux)